# Jquery and ajax within loop and getting single result for message box

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I am very new to java script/jquery/ajax and need some direction.

In my view, there is a dropdown list which is defined as a multiple select. When the user clicks the Save button, I need to send off a call to insert record for the number of items in the multi-select and then return one message stating success or failure of all the inserts.  For example to keep it simple:  view has three fields: F1, F2, F3 with F3 being a multi select.  User enters V1 in F1, V2 in F2, and selects V3A, V3B, V3C  for F3.   So ultimately, the loop will need to try to execute inserts for:

V1, V2, V3A    then V1, V2, V3B    then V1, V2, V3C

I would like a message presented back to the user showing something like:  Three attempts – 2 successful – 1 failed

On my ‘Save’ button, this is the code ..

("#btnSave").click(function () {

```
var getSelectedValue = "";
var getSelectedValueCnt = 0;

var x = document.getElementById("ddl_ValueCode");
for (var i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) {
    if (x.options[i].selected == true) {
        getSelectedValue += x.options[i].value + ",";
        getSelectedValueCnt ++;
    }
}
getSelectedValue = getSelectedValue.substring(0, getSelectedValue.length - 1);
$('#hid_ValueList').val(getSelectedValue);

var myValue = "";
var myCount = 0;
var myMess = "";

for (var ii = 0; ii < getSelectedValue.length; ii++) {

    myValue = getSelectedValue.substr(ii, 1);
    if (myValue != ",") {

        myCount++;
        var viewModel = {
            F1: $("#txt_V1").val(),
            F2: $("#txt_V2").val(),
            F3: myValue
        };


      $.ajax({
            url: '/Information/ABC',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(viewModel),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            beforeSend: function () { $("#DivLoading").dialog("open"); },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                if (data.ResultSuccess) {

                    myMess = myMess + myValue + " ";

                } else {
                    myMess = myMess + data.ResultString;
                }


                if (getSelectedValueCnt == myCount) {
                    $("#DivLoading").dialog("close");
                    $("#SuccessDisplay").html(myMess);
                    $("#SaveSuccessfulXX").dialog("open");
                    $("#btnSave").removeClass("form-primarybutton").addClass("form-disablebutton");

                }
            },

            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#DivLoading").dialog("close");
                $("#ErrorDisplay").html(jqXHR.status + " - " + jqXHR.statusText);
                $("#Error").dialog("open");
            }
        });


    }
}
```

});

It is successfully looping through and doing/attempting the insert, but I don't understand how to have only one message displayed with all the success/fail messages.  Can somebody explain to me simply what is the correct way to achieve what I need? I have read and reread many posts, but do not understand clearly what direction/coding I need to take.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting multiple messages because your error output is inside your for loop.  Instead, you could create an empty container for messages, append them as necessary and output them outside your loop.  Something like this:

```
var myValue = "";
var myCount = 0;
var myMess = "";

var messages = "";  //empty messages container

for (var ii = 0; ii < getSelectedValue.length; ii++) {

myValue = getSelectedValue.substr(ii, 1);
if (myValue != ",") {

    myCount++;
    var viewModel = {
        F1: $("#txt_V1").val(),
        F2: $("#txt_V2").val(),
        F3: myValue
    };


  $.ajax({
        ...
        },

        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            messages += jqXHR.status + " - " + jqXHR.statusText; //add current status message to container
        }
    });


}
}

//display errors outside loop
$("#DivLoading").dialog("close");
$("#ErrorDisplay").html(messages);
$("#Error").dialog("open");
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, but still need to understand how to get the message from each return and present only a combined result.  If data.ResultSuccess is true I want to add ‘myValue’, if false then I add the message sent back in the ResultString.   However, the ‘value’ of myValue is always the same not the ‘current’ one from the ‘for’ loop.  Next, if I use the myMess in the #ErrorDisplay outside the loop it has no value at all.

Comment: @Ask Gotcha.  You can try adding async: false, to your ajax call.  That should fix the myMess var being empty.

Comment: Based on many posts it states that async: false is not a good practice